# One time property binding for Angular

Tags: angular

I have a checkbox I want to set the checked attribute if the current object is in an array but I only want that check to happen once not on change detection.

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="item | inArray: selectedData" (click)="selectItem($event.target.checked, item)">
```

I don't need change detection running that logic after the initial render as the selectItem method adds or removes the item from the array so the checkboxes are in sync. I might have hundreds of these checkboxes per page and I only need the check to happen once. It is a rather expensive method to fire off for every checkbox each time any of the checkboxes are clicked.

Is there a one time binding method that only happens on render rather than change detection?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a boolean variable that represents the initial checked status instead of using the `inArray` pipe.

```js
checked: boolean;

constructor(private inArrayPipe: InArrayPipe) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.checked = this.inArrayPipe.transform(this.item, this.selectedData);
}
```

The `checked` value won't change again in the future after the initialization so the check also happens only once since the `checked` input does not change.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar

Answer (score 0):

My way I solved this is I created an array of checkboxes and I bound to them. Each time I create a new page of data I map the page data to a list of checkboxes.

```
this.pageDataSelected = this.pageData.map(
   item => this.selectedData && this.selectedData.includes(item)
);
```

and then bind the checkboxes to these booleans.

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="pageDataSelected[i]" (click)="selectItem($event.target.checked, item)">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **ChangeDetectionStrategy** **onPush** method in your component. Please refer below code how to use ChangeDetectionStrategy onPush Method.

```
@Component({
  selector: "child-component",
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ this.executeFunction() }}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

During this Change Detection Strategy, the ChildComponent is not always dirty checked, if the parent element is updating the values that are not passed as “@Input” properties to the Child Component, then the child Component should not be dirty checked.